# How to Handing sub-links --"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, selenium-grid

Objective : Script  to click on sub-links one by one and verify page existence

scenario :
when i mouse hover onto the Category Link -- It display the Sub category Links(List) on the right :

as i take back the hover - links(List) does not gets displayed :

Automation : 
I tried to mouse hover on the category link!! 
thus captured the Xpath of the Category link!!
Applied action to mouse over!!
On Mouse hover Captured the x path of the Sub links at 0 index(start)!
Applied "For Each loop"(advance For loop) to capture the sub link x path one by one!!
Within the above for loop , used "action" to click on the sub link!!

Issue : It Clicks the sub - link at index 0 , on later iteration it is not able to catch the Sub-link, even though mouse hover on the category link is done ...

How to get the Sub-link on second ,3rd ........iteration..

Following is the Code :

```
public static WebElement Add_EditCorpUser(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);   


    element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@title='Security Admin']/following::td[1]/span[contains(text(),'Security')]"));
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();    
    List<WebElement> arrayList=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='hideHeader']//span[@id='subMenu']//div[@id='i_2sub']//tbody/tr"));

    List<String> linksname = new ArrayList<>();
     for (WebElement w:arrayList) {
            linksname.add(w.getText());
            System.out.println("value ---------------- --"+ linksname);
            action.moveToElement(w).click().build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

            driver.switchTo().frame(1);

            action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@title='Security Admin']/following::td[1]/span[contains(text(),'Security')]"))).build().perform();  



            Thread.sleep(10000);

     }
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Modified code as per comment----------------------

```
 public static WebElement element=null;
     public static WebElement Add_EditCorpUser(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);   


    element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@title='Security Admin']/following::td[1]/span[contains(text(),'Security')]"));
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();    
    List<WebElement> arrayList=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='hideHeader']//span[@id='subMenu']//div[@id='i_2sub']//tbody/tr"));

    String[] xpa=new String[arrayList.size()];
    for(int i=1;i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        xpa[i]="\".//table[@class='hideHeader']//span[@id='subMenu']//div[@id='i_2sub']//tbody/tr["+i+"]\"";


    }

    for(String a: xpa )
    {
        if(a!=null){
            System.out.println(a);
            action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(a))).click().build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame(1);
            System.out.println("Switched to new frame");
            action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();    

        }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get stale element when you search for an element and before doing any action on it the page has changed/reloaded.

Make sure the page is fully loaded before doing any actions in the page.
First wait for the page to be loaded -> then find the element and execute action.

If you save all links in an array and you want to click on each of them it will not work.
You need to have an array with the selectors of the links and use that array in your for loop.

On the second code you have invalid selector, you have extra double quotes.try

```
xpa[i]="//table[@class='hideHeader']//span[@id='subMenu']//div[@id='i_2sub']//tbody/tr["+i+"]";
```

Keep in mind that xpath is a string, use concatenation, print the string an check it in the browser and update in order to get valid xpath.

Comment: i wrote a new code where i collected the x path of the sublinks and tried to hit on them : but  i am facing here is ---i have collected the xpaths in variable "a" or "xpa" -- when i tried to mouse hover using either a or xpa as shown in the code it throws an error .....however when i put the xpath into the action it runs the code , thus i am not able to make use of stored x paths .......when i print the x paths , everything is fine but when i try to use it via variable ....error thrown as shown in new added image file